# How to assign v-on dinamically with v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a code in Vue that creates the elements of a menu using a v-for, and each element must have a different method when it's clicked.

So far I have this:

```
<span v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems" :key="index">
    <li>
    <a id="listItem">
        <i class="bx" :class="menuItem.icon || 'bx-square-rounded'" />
        <span class="links_name" v-on:click=menuItem.click>{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
    </a>
    <span class="tooltip">{{
        menuItem.tooltip || menuItem.name
    }}</span>
    </li>
</span>
```

How can I assign different funcions on the v-on?

Comment: First you should enclose the function you are calling with double quotes, as in: `v-on:click="menuItem.click"`. You can also use `@click=""` instead of `v-on:click=""`

Comment: does your array of `menuItem` include a `click` method? Seems an odd choice. I'd do something like `@click="click(menuItem)"` and have a method called `click` which takes a single argument, the menuItem being clicked - or even `@click="click(index)"` then of course `index` is the index in `menuItems` that was clicked

Comment: you can store the function in the object and then use it like menuItem.function

Comment: How are `menuItems` and methods defined ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the listener function as a node in the object list.

**Sample Implementation**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [{
        name: 'lg',
        age: 27,
        onClick: function() {
            console.log("First Item Clicked");
        }
      }, {
        name: 'camile',
        age: 27,
        onClick: function() {
            console.log("Second Item Clicked");
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="item.name">
        {{item.name}} - {{item.age}}
        <button @click="item.onClick()">
        Click Me
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" v-model="list[0].name">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, now the function I am trying to call is from another component, but the ref is not recognized. Goes something like this: 
    'menuItems: {
           type: Array,
            default: () => [
              {
                link: "/RegistroEstudiantes",
                name: "Registrar Esudiantes",
                tooltip: "Registro Estudiantes",
                icon: "bx-grid-alt",
                onClick: function() {
                  this.$refs.ProfesorArea.open();
                },
              },'